# How to design MVC framework of an app platform with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, directory-structure

How to design MVC framework of an app platform with Laravel?

The platform is made of multiple apps, each app has different frontends and different logics. For example, one only shows a picture in frontend, and we only need an upload function in its backend; one shows a form in frontend, and we need to create a form builder in backend.

So how can i design the MVC?

Until now, what i do is as below. But it seems too complex. When i want to create a new type of app, I need to create a lot of files. Thus is there any better designs?

```
/app
    /models
        /apps
            /app1
    /http/controllers
        /apps
            /app1
    /services
        /apps
            /app1
    /repository
        /apps
            /app1
    /presenter
        /apps
            /app1
```

Comment: How about automating the process? You can try creating a command.

Comment: @Doom5 That is a way. But what i hope is to find a better design, I dont think this is a good way to implement...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moduler Approch. For Moduler Approach see below link :

[Main Resource](https://ziyahanalbeniz.blogspot.com.tr/2015/03/modular-structure-in-laravel-5.html)

[Laravel Package](https://github.com/Artem-Schander/L5Modular)

[My Article](http://nahid.im/diary/read/23)

And for Automation you can create a console artisan command.